# I want to add an element inside an array, but not getting how to do this using angular

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I want to add another name under subChild in Object. Do we have any method for doing this. In subdomain I have another name. Which I need to add under subchild.
I tried

```
childBD[i].subChild.push(busDomain);
```

I also tried
 `childBD[i].subChild.concat(busDomain);`

but it is throwing an error
TypeError: childBD[i].subChild.push is not a function.
Can anyone please help me resolving this.

Comment: if those prototypes aren't available `childBD[i].subChild` is not an array.

Comment: You will give your childeBD array details with busDomain array values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture above I see that `subChild` is an object and not an array. So there are no functions like `push()` or `concat()` for an object. You can add a property to it like this `childBD[i].subChild.busDomain = busDomain;`

Comment: yes you are right it's a object, I tried your solution but it is adding busDomain under subChild. busDomain contains name: "bsd2", I want to add this whole thing under subChild beneath firsat name. I tried childBD[i].subChild = busDomain; but it is overriding the previous name. Is it possible to add a new name:value  beneath first name:value

Comment: hmm so you want to add the content of your variable as the name of the variable like this: `childBD[i].subchild.bsd2`. If you want to do this you can do the following: `childBD[i].subChild[busDomain] = busDomain;`
PP:
It is impossible to add another variable with the same name as the one that already exists (name). You can either create a new variable or override the value of the first one.

Comment: Another option is to set the name variable to an array containing the two names. You can do it like this: `var names = [ childBD[i].subChild.name, busDomain ];  childBD[i].subChild.name = names;`